# How to change highlight appearance of ListBoxItems

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5

Whenever a ListboxItem is selected, I want the appearance of the selected listbox item to change ( stand out). Below is my code that I have. It works properly and as I'd expect, EXCEPT when I scroll down the listbox, and then try to select another ListBoxItem. Then, some items don't change in appearance at all, some don't de-highlight, or the app crashes, etc. Why??

Delphi XE5 for a Mobile iOS application.

```
procedure TForm5.ListBoxItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item : TListBoxItem;
  C : TColorBox;
  T : TText;
  i : Integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  while i <> ListBox1.Items.Count do begin
    Item := ListBox1.ListItems[i];
    T := Item.Children[1] as TText;
    C := Item.Children[2] as TcolorBox;
    T.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
    C.Visible := False;

    i := i +1;
  end;
  Item := Sender as TListBoxItem;
  T := Item.Children[1] as TText;
  C := Item.Children[2] as TcolorBox;

  T.Color := TAlphaColors.White;
  C.Visible := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of your selected cell. When the user selects another, make sure you redraw the previously selected cell, then draw your newly selected cell.

pseudo code:

```
class property: currentCell

onCellSelection:
previousCell = currentCell
currentCell = selectedCell
redrawCells:[previousCell,currentCell]
```

Your cell drawing code should take into consideration the currentCell property on whether it should draw as hilighted or not.